# Kaminari pagination doesn't display in search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, pagination, kaminari

I'm using Kaminari to paginate my search results.

The search finds 5 results, the page displays 2 results as defined in the per() method in the controller, but it doesn't display any pagination. I can only get to the second page if I manually attach "?page=2" to the URL in the browser window.

**Controller Code:**

```
def show
   @search = Search.find(params[:id])
   @adverts = @search.adverts.page(params[:page]).per(2)
end
```

**View Code:**

```
<ul class="adverts_small">
<% for advert in @adverts %>
   # Render adverts
<% end %>
</ul>

<%= paginate @adverts %>
```

I'm using Kaminari 0.13.0.

Any ideas what could cause this problem?

Comment: does the problem still exist if you hard code a query from the adverts model? (just for testing)